# with keyword and jython 2.5.1

Tags: python, jython

I have the following:

```
with open("c:\xml1.txt","r") as f1, open('c:\somefile.txt','w') as f2:
```

this is giving a syntax error :

```
with open("c:\xml1.txt","r") as f1, open('c:\somefile.txt','w') as f2:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input ',' expecting COLON
```

I'm using the netbeans python plugin which depends on jython 2.5.1

I have added:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

but this hasn't changed anything.

Any advice on what to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement for multiple context managers has only been added in python2.7, see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

For jython2.5, you need the `from __future__ import with_statement` to enable single-context-manager functionality.

Edit:

Interestingly, not even jython2.7b2 supports multiple context managers.

what you can do is nest the contexts:

```
with open("c:/whatever") as one_file:
    with open("c:/otherlocation") as other_file:
        pass  #  or do things
```

Answer (score 0):

In your file paths you have "\" in a couple places, \x is generally used to indicate hexadecimal characters.  Try either using raw strings with "r" or escaping your backslashes with another backslash.

```
with open(r"c:\xml1.txt","r") as f1, open(r'c:\somefile.txt','w') as f2:
```

or

```
with open("c:\\xml1.txt","r") as f1, open('c:\\somefile.txt','w') as f2:
```

Comment: That must not have been the problem (or the only problem).  It was the first thing that jumped out at me when I read your code, it has bitten me in the past.  Sorry it didn't solve your issue.