# For loop: Syntax Error: mismatched input '' expecting EOF

Tags: python, jython

I'm using jython 2.5.1 and netbeans,

I have the following code:

```
import csv
import pprint
import os

column=[]
mycsv = csv.reader(open('F:\lia1.csv'))
for row in mycsv:
    text = row[0].strip()

if text.isdigit():
    column.append(text[-4:])


out=' '.join(column)

f2=open('F:\somefile.txt','w')
f1=open("F:\xml1.txt","r") 

for item in out:
    try:
        text = f1.readline()
        text = text.replace("Keys1028","Keys"+str(item))
        f2.write(text)
```

I have the following error:

```
 for item in out:
    ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input '' expecting EOF
```

if I comment out try: I get:

```
  for item in out:
    ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input '' expecting EOF
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you mean to add a `except:` statement at all?

Comment: You'll need to show us more of your code, because our `out` definition is not complete *either*.

Comment: Also note that the `\x` inside `"F:\xml1.txt"` makes an invalid escape, use `r"F:\xml1.txt"` instead.

Comment: Martin, the list 'out' is made of several hundred 4 digit strings. Iwas using try because from what I read it is good practice to use it with streams. does this help?

Comment: Did you copy this *exactly* from your text editor?  It looks like you started a string with a `'` but ended with a `"`, maybe `'r"` in your last `open` before the loop.

Comment: its right out of the editor

Answer (score 0):

I think it had to do with nesting of statements.

The error was fixed by:

```
with open("c:/whatever") as one_file:
    with open("c:/otherlocation") as other_file:
        pass  #  or do things
```

Please see [with keyword and jython 2.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571785/with-keyword-and-jython-2-5-1/16572002#16572002)